# How to resolve Event Emitter issue in angular

Tags: angular

In my code event emitter is not working. So, How to call event emitter inside testing component.
If any one knows please help to resolve this issue.

autocomplete-overview-example.ts:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.trigger.autocomplete.closed.subscribe(e => {
  console.log('emitted');
  this.closevent.emit();
 }) 
 }
```

testing.component.ts:

```
  callCloseEvent() {
    alert('success');
  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3z5tqr-gbnbze?file=app%2Ftesting%2Ftesting.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE

The issue was further due to the configuration of the appModule in the stackblitz

Before:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [TestingComponent],
  declarations: [AutocompleteOverviewExample, TestingComponent],
  bootstrap: [AutocompleteOverviewExample],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

After:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  declarations: [TestingComponent, AutocompleteOverviewExample],
  bootstrap: [TestingComponent],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

autocomplete-overview-example.ts

```
@Output() closeevent = new EventEmitter(); //<-       typo



 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.trigger.autocomplete.closed.subscribe(e => {
      console.log('emitted');
      this.closeevent.emit(); // <------------------------typo
    })

 }
```

in html it says `closeevent` but in the calling component it says `closevent`

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3z5tqr-yssw5j)

Comment: Not working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3z5tqr-6s2ccm?file=app%2Fautocomplete%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.ts

Comment: This function is not calling: callCloseEvent()

Comment: @EMahanK This is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3z5tqr-yssw5j)

Comment: Is it possible to stop event emitter?

Comment: @EMahanK sorry i thought the issue was to make it work, if you want pass a flag called skip on the emitter and put a if on the alert so that it won't be called

Comment: I mean how to use event.preventDefault(); for event emitter?

Comment: @EMahanK please call it before you do the console.log ('emitter') as e.preventDefault();

Comment: Getting error like "Property preventDefault"does not exit on type 'void'

Comment: Also getting the error in console like Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault')

Comment: mat autocomplete closed event is calling continually three time, But i want to call only closed time. that's why i am trying to use prevent default or stop propagation

Comment: @EMahanK The `closed` of autocomplete does not have a `event` so this cannot and need not be done!

Comment: Can we use any flag? for avoiding multiple calls